# Asignación condicional en JavaScript (var a = a || [];)

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con código en JavaScript y encuentro algunas líneas que hacen esta operación:

```
var a = a || [];
```

Lo que he visto en todas esas líneas que he identificado es que el patrón es el mismo: declarar una variable y asignarle a esta el valor de la operación o de la variable recién creada contra un *array* vacío

¿Cuál es el objetivo de realizar esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay que tener en cuenta que javascript, cuando duplicas la declaración de una variable, no emite ninguna advertencia. Simplemente reduce ambas declaraciones  a una declaración única al principio de la función.

```
function w() {
  var a; 
  // codigo en el medio
  var a;
}
```

se reduce como `var a = undefined;` al principio de la función.

Ahora, en una función donde `a` se declara como argumento, pasa lo mismo, estarías duplicando la declaración, y javascript reducirá el duplicado a una única declaración.

#### A la Respuesta

Esta es técnica se usaba en ECMAScript 5 para declarar el valor por defecto de los argumentos.

Ejemplo: (ECMAScript 5)

```
function x(a) {
  var a = a || []; // valor por defecto de a, las declaraciones se unen.
  // hacer algo con a
}

x(); // sin argumentos, a se establecerá como []
x({}); // a se establecerá como {}
```

Personalmente creo que no es muy recomendable utilizar `var` cuando ya definiste la variable como argumento. Es mejor dejarla sin la palabra `var`.

```
function x(a) {
  a = a || [];
  // hacer algo con a
}
```

Esta es la forma menos propensa a errores. Un programador no experto en javascript podría creer, por sentido común, que la segunda declaración de `a`, oculta la primera, cosa que seria un error de su parte.

Considera este ejemplo:

```
function x(a) {

  // codigo aqui

  if (condicion) {
     var a = a || []; // esta a es la misma a que en la declaracion de funcion
     // hacer algo con a
  }
}
```

Como ya dije, la declaración se mueve al principio y `var a` **no** esta declarando una nueva variable que es valida solamente dentro del if. Es la misma variable `a` para toda la función. A diferencia de otros lenguajes.

Por ultimo, en ECMAScript 2015 la técnica ya no es necesaria por que puedes declarar el valor por defecto en la declaración de función de esta forma:

```
function x(a = []) {
  // hacer algo con a
}
```

Comment: Cabe mencionar que es [una característica nueva](http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues) (default function parameters) que no está implementada aún al 100%, se puede validar su implementación en: [ES6 compatibily table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Answer (score 7):

El objetivo de hacer eso es mantener el valor de la variable si ya había sido definida con anterioridad.

En ese caso en particular (`var a = a || [];`) lo que se está haciendo es que si la variable `a` ya había sido definida anteriormente en el código, se deja tal y como estaba (`a`). Pero si aún no ha sido definida, se inicializa a un array vacío (`[]`).

Comment: Creo que la suya se entiende mejor y ademas fue mas rapido +1. Saludos

Answer (score 4):

Todas las respuestas hasta ahora son correctas, pero ninguna explica por qué así que voy a añadirlo.

El operador `||`, como en muchos otros lenguajes, es el operador de *disyunción lógica*, es decir, una operación **OR**.  Ahora bien, en JavaScript, este operador no devuelve `true` o `false` como cabría esperar, sino que *devuelve el primer valor que se evalúe como cierto en la cadena*.  Si dicho valor no existe, es decir, todos los argumentos son *falsos*, se devolverá el último valor de la cadena.

Así, `var a = a || []` funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Se evalúa el valor de `a`:

  - Si `a` contiene un valor *cierto*, se devuelve su valor.
  - Si `a` contiene un valor *falso* (por ejemplo `undefined`, si no se ha pasado el argumento), continúa la evaluación.
- Se evalúa el valor de `[]`:

  - Al ser el último valor en la cadena, se devuelve directamente.

De esta manera, a más alto nivel, tenemos:
1

- Si `a` está definida, devuelve su valor.
- Si `a` no está definida, devuelve `[]`.

Como bien se ha dicho previamente, esto se utiliza generalmente para declarar *valores por defecto* de argumentos de función.  Se ha de tener especial cuidado con este patrón si la función acepta como válidos cualquiera de los siguientes valores:

- `null`
- `false`
- `0`
- `''` (un `string` vacío)

Todos estos valores se evalúan como falsos, por lo que podríamos obtener falsos positivos.  Por supuesto, si estos valores son los valores por defecto, nada cambiará: `a || 0` devolverá `0` tanto si `a` es `0` como si no está definida.

En caso de que alguno de dichos valores sea válido, utiliza el siguiente patrón en su lugar:

```
var a = (a !== undefined) ? a : []
```

Por supuesto, utiliza el valor por defecto deseado en lugar de `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Viene a ser algo así como:

Si existe la variable `a` y está definida, deja la variable `a` tal y como estaba, y si no esta definida, asigna una referencia a un nuevo `array` vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Sirve para definir un valor por defecto en caso que `a` no existe

```
a = a || []; //definir [] si a no existe
```

También es la forma para definir valores por defecto en los parámetros de las funciones

```
function drinkBeers(beers) {
   beers = beers || valorXdefecto;
}
```